# Button created through class is not getting packed rightfully in tkinter GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

In my project, there is a multiple use of buttons with same text, color, font size etc. So, I created a button class for that so that i don't have to give the above arguments again and again. But the problem is, the buttons are not getting packed inside the master/root/frame I assign, instead they get packed on the main root window.
Here is a simple code where, the button is not packed inside the label frame.

```
from tkinter import *

class BoxFrame (LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, master = None, bd = 4, relief = GROOVE, labelanchor = 'n', font = 'Arial 10 bold', fg = 'navy blue', *args, **kwargs):
        LabelFrame.__init__(self, master, bd = 4, relief = GROOVE, labelanchor = 'n', font = 'Arial 10 bold', fg = 'navy blue',*args, **kwargs)


class ViewButtons (Button):
    def __init__(self, master = None, text = 'View Result', font = ('', 9, 'bold'), bg = 'Pale Green', *args, **kwargs):
        Button.__init__(self, master = None, text = 'View Result', font = ('', 9, 'bold'), bg = 'Pale Green', *args, **kwargs)
        self.pack(pady = 20)

### Main Program ###
root = Tk()

box = BoxFrame(root, width = 100, height = 50)
box.pack_propagate(0)
box.pack()

button = ViewButtons(box)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are explicitly setting the `master` to `None` in this line of code:

```
Button.__init__(self, master = None, ...)
```

You need to instead pass in the value of `master` that was given by the caller:

```
Button.__init__(self, master, ...)
```

Comment: Please, tell me one more thing. Since, the text, font, color etc. are common attributes so I passed them in the __init__ method. Is this the right way to do so???

Answer (score 1):

Your question has already been properly answered, but here is an answer to a question you did not ask, but definitely need to know. You are creating a class to hold a `Button`, but your class does not add anything to the `Button`. It would seem like the only reason you are making the class is to "internally" assign all the `options` and make it `pack` itself. However, even in that you are repeating yourself. In all of that you didn't even pass a `command` to the button, so what you really have is a very over-engineered `Button` that doesn't do anything.

A better solution would be to prepare `kwargs` before-hand and then use them. One way you can do this is via `dataclasses` as exampled below. Doing it this way you can create a default 'style' for your `Buttons` and overwrite just the parts you want to change if you need some other slightly different buttons. Determining what to put in the `dataclass` is very simple. Go find the docs for whatever widget you want to make a `dataclass` for and just list everything that is considered an `option`. You only want to exclude `options` from the `dataclass` that always change (like `command` and `text`), and input those arguments manually ~ as exampled below.

```
import tkinter as tk
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass
class Button_dc:
    activeforeground:   str = 'black'
    activebackground:   str = 'white'
    foreground:         str = 'white'
    background:         str = 'black' 
    highlightcolor:     str = 'red'
    relief:             str = 'flat'
    justify:            str = 'center'
    font:               str = 'Calibri 14 bold'
    compound:           str = 'left'
    state:              str = 'normal'
    underline:          int = -1
    wraplength:         int = -1
    padx:               int = 2
    pady:               int = 2
    border:             int = 2
    width:              int = 0
    height:             int = 0
    
    
DefaultButton = asdict(Button_dc()) #default
SpecialButton = asdict(Button_dc(padx=60, pady=60, font='Helvetica 12')) #noticeably different


class App(tk.Tk):
    WIDTH  = 800
    HEIGHT = 600
    TITLE  = 'Example'
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        
        #this is emphatically more tidy than creating a custom widget class every time you want to style a widget 
        tk.Button(self, text='view', command=self.view, **DefaultButton).grid(column=0)
        tk.Button(self, text='click', command=self.click, **SpecialButton).grid(column=0)
        
    def view(self):
        print('I have been viewed')
        
    def click(self):
        print('I have been clicked')
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.title(App.TITLE)
    app.geometry(f'{App.WIDTH}x{App.HEIGHT}')
    app.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    app.mainloop()
```

If you actually do need to extend a `widget` you can still use this method to efficiently set the options ~ as below:

```
class ComplexButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master, text, command, **kwargs):
        #this will still default to everything in Button_dc that is not explicitly set in kwargs
        self.default = asdict(Button_dc(**kwargs))
        tk.Button.__init__(self, master, text=text, command=command, **self.default)
        
        self.hover = self.default.copy()
        self.hover['background'] = 'red'
        
        self.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)
        
    def on_enter(self, event):
        self.configure(**self.hover)
        
    def on_leave(self, event):
        self.configure(**self.default)
```

Comment: That's nice idea! 